# use L1-convergence to show integral convergence

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

Let $f\in L^1([0,1])$, $g_n$ a sequence of continuous functions that converges in $L^1$ to some $g\in L^1([0,1])$. Now my question is: Does $\int_0^1 f(t)e^{g_n(t)} dt$ converge to $\int_0^1 f(t)e^{g(t)} dt$?

edit: I forgot to mention that we may assume that $g$ is bounded, but this bound is not a bound for the $g_n$.

Comment: is $t \mapsto f(t) e^{g(t)}$ integrable?

Comment: Yes. I may assume that $g$ is bounded.

Comment: Without further assumptions, this is very false.

Comment: @SebastianBechtel: You should add that assumption to the question. Are the $g_n$ also bounded by the same bound?

Comment: @PhoemueX counterexample?

Comment: @copper.hat I have added the information to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f=1$, $g=0$ and $g_n$ be defined as interpolation between the points $(0,0), (0,1-{2 \over n^2}),$ $(n,1-{1 \over n^2}), (n,1)$. It is straightforward to check that $\|g-g_n\|_1=\|g_n\|_1 \le {2 \over n}$.

However, $\int f(t) e^{g_n(t)} dt \ge e^n {1 \over n^2}$, which is unbounded.